# What are the maximum amounts one can fund an unnegotiated channel across various lightning implementations?

Tags: lightning-network-daemon, ln-opening-channels, eclair, lightning-development-kit, wumbo-channels

It is 0.16777215 BTC [for Core Lightning](https://docs.corelightning.org/reference/lightning-fundchannel).
How much is it for [LDK](https://lightningdevkit.org/introduction/), LND and Eclair?

P.S. If there exist any other implementations that I've left out in this question, the mention of them is most welcome in the answers.

Answer (score 2):

The 0.16777215 BTC limit is a lightning spec requirement - nodes must negotiate (which really just means marking a feature as supported) the wumbo feature in order to have channels larger than that. That said, all nodes have supported wumbo for quite some years now, so you shouldn't have any issue opening channels greater than that with any node.

Most nodes have a configuration knob to change the maximum channel size, LDK's defaults to 0.16777215 BTC - https://docs.rs/lightning/latest/lightning/util/config/struct.ChannelHandshakeLimits.html#structfield.max_funding_satoshis